# Why this dart function change the value of the variable matches?

Tags: list, flutter, function, dart, variables

I can't understand this:

```
//Globals variables
List<int> results = [1,1];
List<List<int>> matches = [[1,3],[2,4]];

void main() {
  print("before");
  print(matches); //output: [[1,3],[2,4]]
  List<int> losers = getEliminatedPlayer(matches);
  print("after");
  print(matches); //output: [[3],[4]]
}

List<int> getEliminatedPlayer(List<List<int>> matches) {
  List<List<int>> losers = matches;

  for (var i = 0; i < losers.length; i++) {
    losers[i].remove(losers[i][results[i] - 1]);
  }

  var flattened = losers.expand((loser) => loser).toList();

  print(flattened);
  return flattened;
}
```

Why even if i don't work on the **matches** variable it **changes**?
How can I avoid it?

Comment: `List losers = matches;` does not create a clone of `matches` but will just clone the variable. So both `matches` and `losers` will point to the same psychical list in memory and any list modifications done on `losers` will therefore also happen on `matches`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List losers = matches` does not make a copy of the matches list but merely gives it an additional variable that points to the exact same list. So changes made to either variable will be reflected in both. To solve you need to make a deep copy of it. In your case you could do this:

```
List getEliminatedPlayer(List matches) {
  List losers = matches.map((e) => e.toList()).toList();
  for (var i = 0; i < losers.length; i++) {
  losers[i].remove(losers[i][results[i] - 1]);
  }   
  var flattened = losers.expand((loser) => loser).toList();
  print(flattened);
  return flattened;
}
```